# EntLib 6 - creating full design integrated exception handler

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, design-time

I am trying to create a fully integrated exception handler for EntLib 6.

This is my handler skeleton:

```
[ConfigurationElementType(typeof(LogHandlerData))]
public class LogHandler : IExceptionHandler
{

    public LogHandler(String message) { }

    public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
    {
        return exception;
    }
}
```

for configuration I created a DataHandler class:

```
public class LogHandlerData : ExceptionHandlerData
{
    private const String MESSAGE = "Message";

    public LogHandlerData() : base(typeof(LogHandler)) { }

    public LogHandlerData(string name, string message)
        : base(name, typeof(LogHandler))
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(MESSAGE, IsRequired = false)]
    [Editor(CommonDesignTime.EditorTypes.MultilineText, CommonDesignTime.EditorTypes.FrameworkElement)]
    public String Message
    {
        get { return (String)this[MESSAGE]; }
        set { this[MESSAGE] = value; }
    }

    public override IExceptionHandler BuildExceptionHandler()
    {
        return new LogHandler(Message);
    }
}
```

Something seems wrong. When I pick the assemlby using the EntLib-config-util, no avialable handlers appear. If I change the **ConfigurationElementType** to *CustomHandlerData* it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know attribute names are case-sensitive. Probably mistake in the XML configuration. By the way here a very good tutorial: [Creating a Custom Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664483%28PandP.50%29.aspx).

Comment: This is exactly the tutorial I am following. There is no mistake in the XML, since the provide does not appear in the config util, it is not configured at all...